# not able to found the file name in the below code in java

Tags: java, file

I have the below java code in which i am passing a file name to the the calling method lets say below code is initially the code is

```
File file = new File("C:\\oabc.csv");
String filename = file.getName();
s = getFileExtension(file) ;
if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(".csv"))
{
     convertcsvtoexcel(filename);
}
```

now since there is an csv file that is being passed so it will call the method to convert the csv to excel till that stage i have tried to debug i am getting the filename but below is the convert code that is called in which it not find the filename throwing an exception that file not found exception

```
 public static  void  convertcsvtoexcel(String filename) throws Exception {
      ArrayList arList=null;
      ArrayList al=null;
      String thisLine; 
      int count=0; 
      FileInputStream file1 = null ;
      file1   = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));

      DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(file1);
      int i=0;
```

But it in the above code it throws the error at line  `file1   = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));` saying that it does not found file abc.csv at the specified location

Answer (score 0):

getName() returns the file name without any directory information, so in

```
 String name=file.getName();
 File file2=new File(name);
```

file2 and file are not pointing to the same file, unless file is in the current directory.

In your code, pass a File object to your method to avoid path conversion issues.

Comment: what doesn't work? Passing the File object? Have you tested if file.exists() return true?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `convertcsvtoexcel(getPath())`.

Comment: no it does not work it will be great if you please can post the code so  thati can grasp completely

Comment: @user1906154 try file.exists() before file.getPath()

Answer (score 0):

in the following line of code you are just passing the file name.To make it work pass the entire file path + file name.

```
file1   = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));


file1   = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\oabc.csv")); this should work.
```

Comment: no it does not work gettig same file not found exception

Comment: check if the file exists C:\\oabc.csv

Comment: File file = new File("c:/oabc.csv");
  System.out.println(file.exists());